# How to determine p in a Poisson Random Variable

Tags: probability, random-variables

This is Problem 2.2 from Tsitsiklis, Bertsekas, Introduction to Probability, 2nd edition.

> You go to a party with 500 guests. What is the probability that
>   exactly one other guest has the sam birthday as you? Calculate this
>   exactly and also approximately by using the Poisson PMF. For
>   simplicity, exclude birthdays on February 29.

My first thought was that p should be $(1/365)^2$. The idea: p is the probability that event A is X date and B is that same X date.

$P(A \cap B)$ for independent events = $P(A) * P(B)$ = $(1/365) * (1/365)$

My second thought was that p should be (1/365). The idea: p is the probability of B is X date given A is also X date.

$P(A | B)$ with conditional probability = $P(A) * P(B|A) = 1 * 1/365 = 1/365$

I assigned 1 to P(A) since my birthday is given and is certain to be on that date.

How do you determine what p is?

[image: solution from the book]

Comment: Hint:  the exact distribution is binomial with success probability $\frac 1{365}$ (of course we are making all the usual assumptions about birthdays).

Comment: Find a friend of yours and think what is the probability to have the same day birthday, it's 1/365. Then find another friend and think the same it's 1/365. Your friends are independent from each other. So the number of your friends having the same birthday as you follows  Binom(n,1/365)